# MDB JBoss 6.1 Server side is not responding

Tags: java, jboss

I have created a JMS project both client & server. My client is a simple Java app & server is a web app.While I am sending the msgs using client I am getting an error on the server.

2014-03-12 17:00:52,991 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) Connection failure has been detected: Did not receive data from /10.1.20.219:63869. It is likely the client has exited or crashed without closing its connection, or the network between the server and client has failed. You also might have configured connection-ttl and client-failure-check-period incorrectly. Please check user manual for more information. The connection will now be closed. [code=3]
2014-03-12 17:00:52,994 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 7ccb43c0-a9d9-11e3-8873-0024e8c8aec3
2014-03-12 17:00:52,995 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) Cleared up resources for session 7ccb43c0-a9d9-11e3-8873-0024e8c8aec3*

All the msgs delivered by the client are appeared  the queue. But my MDB bean is not responding. Please help.

Code for Bean

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import  javax.jms.*;
/**
 * Created by manodyas on 3/12/14.
 */
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "MsgBean.java", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",propertyValue = "/queue/TestABC"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientFailureCheckPeriod", propertyValue = "600000"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionTTL", propertyValue = "-1")
})

//@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",propertyValue = "queue/TestABC") })
class MsgBean implements  MessageListener{
public MsgBean()
{
}
public void onMessage(Message message)
{
    System.out.println("test");
    if (message instanceof  TextMessage)
    {
        System.out.println("Order Accepted...!!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Other..");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings you can try (i cannot test your specific code right now, so i´m not sure if this will help you). If you can test the 2 suggestions bellow and report the results to us, that would be appreciated.

**Configure / add Extensios element**

Add extension element `<extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>` inside  element.

**Configure ClientFailureCheckPeriod and TTL parameters (try configuring this not only in the MDB)**

If the client does not receive any packets for client-failure-check-period milliseconds then it will consider the connection failed and will either initiate fail-over, or call any SessionFailureListener instances (or ExceptionListener instances if you are using JMS) depending on how it has been configured.

For JMS, the check period is defined by the ClientFailureCheckPeriod attribute on a HornetQConnectionFactory instance. If JMS connection factory instances are being deployed directly into JNDI on the server side, it can be specified in the JBOSS_DIST/jboss-as/server//deploy/hornetq/hornetq-jms.xml configuration file, using the parameter client-failure-check-period.

The default value for the client failure check period is 30000ms (30 seconds). A value of -1 means the client will never fail the connection on the client side if no data is received from the server. Typically this is much lower than the connection TTL value to allow clients to reconnect in case of transitory failure.

Another way is configuring this using annotations in the MDB (and i can see in your code that you are already doing this)

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientFailureCheckPeriod", propertyValue = "600000")

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionTTL", propertyValue = "-1")
```

**Others parameters that you can try:**

More parameters here: http://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20EAP/6.1.0/subsystem/messaging/hornetq-server/connection-factory/index.html

```
call-failover-timeout The timeout to use when fail over is in process (in ms).**
Attribute   Value
Default Value    -1
Type     LONG
Nillable     true
Expressions Allowed  true
```

---

```
failover-on-initial-connection True to fail over on initial connection.
Attribute   Value
Default Value    false
Type     BOOLEAN
Nillable     true
Expressions Allowed
```

---

```
 reconnect-attempts The reconnect attempts.
 Attribute  Value
 Default Value   0
 Type    INT
 Nillable    true
 Expressions Allowed     true
```

---

```
 retry-interval The retry interval.
 Attribute  Value
 Default Value   2000
  Type   LONG
 Nillable    true
 Expressions Allowed     true
```

---

**Sources:**

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/remote-jms-client-and-ejb3-mdb-consumer-eclipse-jboss-7-1/

https://community.jboss.org/thread/233579?_sscc=t

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/HornetQ_User_Guide/ch15s02.html

http://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20EAP/6.1.0/subsystem/messaging/hornetq-server/connection-factory/index.html